# Processing large CSV's using dataflow jobs

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to process 6GB CSV's file (750 MB in GZ) using GCP dataflow jobs. I am using machineType as n1-standard-4, which is 15GB RAM size with 4vCPU's.

My Data Flow Code

```
PCollection<TableRow> tableRow = lines.apply("ToTableRow", ParDo.of(new 
StringToRowConverter()));

static class StringToRowConverter extends DoFn<String, TableRow> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        String inputLine = c.element();
        String[] split = inputLine.split(",");
        TableRow output = new TableRow();
       c.output(new TableRow().set("id", split[0]).set("apppackage", split[1]));
         }
}
```

1. My Job is running since last 2 hours and still not processed.
2. Once I break manually this large file in small parts, it works properly.
3. I have to process 400GB of compressed files to put in bigquery.All zipped Files are in GCP storage.

My query is if only 6GB file is processing in so much time, how can I process 400GB of zipped files?

Is there way I can optimise this process so that I will be able to insert this data in my BQ.

Answer (score 1):

6GB in CSV is *not much data*. CSV is just an really inefficient way of storing numerical data, and for string-alike data, it still carries significant overhead and is hard to parse, and impossible to seek to specific positions at rest (need to be parsed first). So, we can be pretty optimistic that this will actually work out, data wise. It's an import problem.

Don't roll your own parser. For example: What about fields that contain a `,` in their text?  There's enough CSV parsers.

You say you want to get that data into your BigQuery – so go google's way and follow:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#bigquery-import-file-java

as bigquery already comes with it's own Builder that supports CSV.

Comment: This is how my CSV  file have data "1","com.something",myfile,"7.16.0.507","1","12/1/2016 0:00","9ab436f4796b344","a","b". Another thing is I have to pull only processed data not all the fields from CSV so I have used pCollection data flow API. Is there any modification in current code suggested?How do you suggest to parse this file?

Comment: I answered that in my answer: don't parse it yourself, use the csv builder from Google, and then filter the read data. Or at least use another parser that's widely used and not written by yourself.

Comment: Can you suggest by changing above mention code for using already available parser?

Comment: Yes. READ MY ANSWER.  change the code by replacing your own parser with Google's parser. End of story.